# Can anyone see why dropbox won't execute in a text only install on ubuntu server using a system user account?

Tags: ubuntu, backup, ubuntu-10.04, dropbox

I've been trying to set up dropbox on an ubuntu 10.04.2 server to use for backup. I don't want dropbox to be tied to my user account on the server as someone may take over as administrator with a different user account next year. To achieve this I've been following the instructions on http://wiki.dropbox.com/TipsAndTricks/UbuntuServerInstall.

The problem is when it comes to executing the dropox daemon to register the account I get the following error message...

```
dropbox@thomas:~$ /usr/local/dropbox/dropboxd
-su: /usr/local/dropbox/dropbox: No such file or directory
```

I'm using the following commands to install and set up dropox...

```
sudo -s (from my personal account on the server)
groupadd dropbox; useradd -r -d /var/dropbox -g dropbox -s /bin/false dropbox
mkdir -p /usr/local/dropbox /etc/dropbox
chown dropbox.dropbox /var/dropbox; chmod 700 /var/dropbox
wget -O /tmp/dropbox.tar.gz http://www.dropbox.com/download/?plat=lnx.x86
tar xvzf /tmp/dropbox.tar.gz -C /usr/local/dropbox --strip 1
su -l dropbox -s /bin/bash; umask 0027
/usr/local/dropbox/dropboxd
```

The file permissions on the dropboxd and dropbox files are...

```
dropbox@thomas:~$ ls -la /usr/local/dropbox/dropbox*
-rwxr-xr-x 2 cje46 cje46 11329751 2011-04-26 06:37 /usr/local/dropbox/dropbox
-rwxr-xr-x 1 cje46 cje46      238 2011-04-26 06:37 /usr/local/dropbox/dropboxd
```

And to be clear the command is being executed by the dropbox system user.

Hope someone out there has had the same problem and would be able to lend a hand cos this has got me really stumped!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved - Needed to use the 64 bit version rather than the 32 bit version of dropbox I had installed.

Answer (score 1):

The error message indicates that the dropbox user's su process cannot see the file `/usr/local/dropbox/dropbox`. What are the permissions on the directory `/usr/local/dropbox`? You may need to give group or other execute permissions on `/usr/local/dropbox`.